# How do I create a query with greater than one date and not between some other dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So I need to pull back data that is after 1st jan 2017 but NOT between Oct 2016 and 31st dec 2016

This is my current code:

```
SELECT [SequenceID]
  ,[AppointmentDate]
FROM dbo].[AmsAppointment]

where AppointmentDate >= Convert(datetime, '2017-01-01' ) and AppointmentDate <= Convert(datetime, '2016-10-01' )
```

I know the code is wrong so please help me.

Comment: Is that not the same as > '12/31/2017' ?

Comment: You want to find a date bigger (=later) than `2017-01-01` and smaller (=earlier) than `2016-10-01` ???

Comment: Here is a [great article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) how to check time ranges (and how one should not...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways, but I think a `not between` would work best:

```
SELECT [SequenceID], [AppointmentDate]
FROM [dbo].[AmsAppointment]
where
  AppointmentDate >= '2017-01-01' and
  AppointmentDate not between '2016-10-01' and '2017-12-31'
```

And maybe your example just that, but in your scenario, since the ranges overlap, this really translates to:

```
 AppointmentDate >= '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: Look at the article I've linked below the question. It is a *bad habit to kick* to check date ranges with `BETWEEN`. Especially if you do not deal with *naked dates*, if there is a time portion involved, people very often get unexpected results...